# Creating a method in Java that will chain to other methods and call fail() if the previous method in the chain throws an exception?

Tags: java, generics, chaining

Here's what I'm trying to accomplish. I'm in a Java unit test using Mockito. I want to create a generic method for my project called `orFailIfExceptionThrown()` that I can chain to any method call in the test and basically just have it call `fail("An unexpected exception was thrown", e)` inside the method. I'm not *thaaaat* interested in whether I should be doing this, as I can see both sides of why I should or should not do this. I'm just interested in how it could be done, from a pure Java learning standpoint.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what you can't do, and a preferable alternative:

```
method().failOnExcept();     // BAD: as soon as method() terminates unexpectedly
                             // failOnExcept() cannot be called - instead, control flow
                             // shifts to a catch block (error handling) or the caller
                             // of the method (if error handling failed/re-throws)
failOnExcept(() -> method()) // GOOD: we attempt to try method(); if it fails,
                             // failOnExcept() will handle it somehow
```

> I'm not thaaaat interested in whether I should be doing this, as I can see both sides of why I should or should not do this. I'm just interested in how it could be done, from a pure Java learning standpoint.

With this in mind, I'm not going to debate the merits of the alternative here - just know that the primary reason we don't do this, is because it can't be done.